# Does Visual Studio have a "don't format my cshtml at all" option

Tags: visual-studio, razor

Below is an example of how my code routinely gets formatted in cshtml by Visual Studio. I'd like an option that says, just leave my code completely alone, I'll format it how I want

[image]

You'd think this would be in Tools->Options but I've looked under ASP.NET Web Forms, HTML, Razor (ASP.NET Core) but I can't see a relevant option. This is for a MVC project